# Can we replace average pooling with strides and downsampling?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pooling

The https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.6806.pdf Sriving for simplicity talks of how we could replace max pooling with an additional convolutional layer and stride r = 2. But can the same be achieved with average pooling instead ?

Answer (score 0):

The point of the article is to show that the pooling operation can be learned instead of being hardcoded:

> We emphasize that that this replacement can also be seen as learning
>   the pooling operation rather than fixing it

Even though they only experimented with max-pooling the conclusion seems transposable to other pooling like average pooling as the replacement convolutional layer will likely learn this transformation.

The point is that a simple convolution with stride 2 can replace **any** pooling operation.